# Column must contain value; if yes, then the column offset to that value must contain another value

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first time writing a question, so please excuse me if my post is confusing and/or need more details.

As the topic header suggests, I've run into a problem of extracting certain values from a range where multiple conditions must be met.

```
Sub entryRetrieve()
'entryRetrieve - Macro to retrieve data from a certain range in the 'data 
 sheet' based on values from the entry sheet

'Defined worksheets'
Dim dataWS As Worksheet: Set dataWS = Worksheets("DATA")
Dim entryWS As Worksheet: Set entryWS = Worksheets("Indtastningsark")

'Defined values which is chosen based on a drop down menu in the 'entry sheet' '
Dim Initials As String: Initials = entryWS.Range("Initialer").Value
Dim Month As Long: Month = entryWS.Range("Måned").Value

'Ranges where copied values from the retrieved data hopefully should be placed'
Dim Tasks As Range: Set Tasks = entryWS.Range("J15:L24")
Dim Percentages As Range: Set Percentages = entryWS.Range("L15:L24")

'Function to sort through data in 'dataWS' and find if values exists. If yes, copy the range offset to the rows'
'This basically isn't working :( '
For Each cell In dataWS.Range("B2:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    If cell.Value = Month Then
        If cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Initials Then
            MsgBox "found"
            'Copy the following 11 rows'
            Else
            MsgBox "Initials not found"
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

So what I hope to happen, in written word, is that;
based on given values "initials" and "month", the function finds it within - respectively - column "A" and column "B". In the rows where these two values exists (and match) the function copies the values contained within column "C", "D" and "E" and pastes it into the defined 'Tasks' range in the other sheet.

Picture attached - green is values 'initials' and 'month'; blue is to be copied.

[Picture of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHZMv.png)

[Picture of where data has to be pasted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVeNA.png)

Hopefully you understand my question. If not please ask :)

EDIT:

Solution was found thanks to Samuel!

Though I've now stumbled upon another problem in relation to this: Being able to delete the rows instead, with the containing data.

```
With dataWS
    For Each Cell In .Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
        If Cell.Value = Month Then
            If Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Initials Then
                 Dim answer As Integer
                 answer = MsgBox("Er du sikker på at du vil slette registreringen: " & Month & " for '" & Initials & "'" _
                            , vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Slet indtastning")
                 deleteRange = .Range(.Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Offset(0, 1).Column), .Cells(Cell.Offset(9, 0).Row, Cell.Offset(0, 3).Column)) 'Can also be written as Range("C" & Cell.Row, "E" & Cell.Row + 11)

                 If answer = vbYes Then
                     '*** THIS DOESNT WORK ;( ***'
                     .Rows(deleteRange).EntireRow.Delete 
                 End If
           End If
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Second edit - I got the deletion of data function working thanks to Samuel agian!

```
With dataWS
    For Each Cell In .Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
        If Cell.Value = Month Then
            If Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Initials Then
                Dim answer As Integer
                answer = MsgBox("Er du sikker på at du vil slette registreringen: '" & Format(Month, "[$-da-DK]mmmm") & "' for '" & Initials & "'" _
                                , vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Slet indtastning")
                If answer = vbYes Then
                    .Range(.Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Column), .Cells(Cell.Offset(11, 0).Row, Cell.Column)).EntireRow.Delete

                    MsgBox "Registrering slettet!"
                    Opgaver.ClearContents
                Else
                    Exit For
                Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're question is really lacking 1 major thing, *an actual question!*. From what I see you are declaring a bunch of variables and assigning them with worksheet values, so we know we have some data to work with, but we would need to know a bit more about what values need to be checked and if they are true, what offset comes in to play (is it a column to the left or right, or 2 or 4 or 100?) so if you can edit your question with some more into to paint the picture we will be able to help!

Comment: Hello Samuel - thank you for the welcome! 
I've edited my question a bit now.

Comment: Ok, It's a bit clearer now, but what are you *expecting* to happen, and what *actually* happens?

Comment: Alright Samuel, I've tried detailing it out what i would hope (expect) to happen. :)

Comment: Ok, what happens when you run your code? I've put it into a test worksheet and the logic is fine... I got my expected results, so I'm thinking maybe the values you are assigning aren't matching somewhere.

Comment: If the values assigned isn't matching (or existing) that's good, since then should just give s MsgBox saying entry not found. Though, it's the next step after the values match and exists; then it should copy the values in column C, D and E based on the matching values on the rows. This step I'm fiding difficult in creating.

Comment: Do you get the message box confirming the values have been found when they match?

Comment: And am I correct that the data to be copied is 3 columns by 11 rows?

Comment: I don't recieve any msg box confirming. And yes you are correct in your assumption.

Comment: Also, I've added a link to a picture for visuals.

Comment: I need to run, my kidlette needs some attention but I'll come back and add some more info to my answer later on tonight.

Comment: Of course! I just appreciate how you're helping! :)

Comment: Give it a go, and if you have any questions about it put them in the answer comments and I'll get to them in a few hours (or tomorrow, depending on if I fall asleep).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a re-write of your code with some minor changes. I've left some comments in the code to provide some info about why the change is there or what the line does.

To briefly explain it; I declare variables for your values to be checked, LastRow to be used the same way you were, but I prefer it in a variable for readability. Both sheets the same (but for my testing I used `Sheet2` and `Sheet3`) and lastly an array for your range to 'copy' and a few range variables for loops and the destination to 'paste' to.

For the sake of testing, I assigned set values to `Month` and `Initials`.

I included some with statements, again to help readability.

Your `For Each...Loop` was fine how it was and returned expected results when I ran it. I suspect when you tried it your values may not have actually been what you expected as I got each `MsgBox` when I expected it (I also included a bit extra info to the message for debugging).

Instead of `Copy` and `Paste` which are not the most efficient functions to use, I have a loop run through each row in Column B looking for the month in numeric format - (January = 1, February = 2 etc.) - and if found the next conditional statement looks for the string "SE" in column A.

If the month is correct but the string is not matched, the `MsgBox "Initials not found on row: " & Cell.Row` fires, however if they do match, `CopyRange` is assigned the values from range `C6:E17`.

The `Destination` is then created, starting with the top left cell of the range and then dynamically resized to fit the array values. Then the array is written to the `Destination` range.

The array goes accross each row then down to the next. See below the code for sample input and output screenshots.

### The Code

```
Sub CAJTest()

Dim Month As Long
Dim Initials As String
Dim LastRow As Long

Dim entryWS As Worksheet
Dim dataWS As Worksheet
Set entryWS = Sheet3 '<~~ assign your correct sheet here
Set dataWS = Sheet2  '<~~ assign your correct sheet here

Dim CopyRange As Variant 'To be used as an array for our values.
Dim Destination As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Tasks As Range

Month = 6
Initials = "SE"
LastRow = dataWS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'I prefer to assign the last row to a variable

With dataWS
    For Each Cell In .Range("B2:B" & LastRow) 'I feel this is more readable than the above to find the last row being in this statement
        If Cell.Value = Month Then
            If Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Initials Then
                MsgBox "found " & Month & " and " & Initials & " on row: " & Cell.Row
                'the next line creates an array CopyRange with dimensions 1 to 12, 1 to 3 and assigns the values to the array
                CopyRange = .Range(.Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Offset(0, 1).Column), .Cells(Cell.Offset(11, 0).Row, Cell.Offset(0, 3).Column)) 'Can also be written as Range("C" & Cell.Row, "E" & Cell.Row + 11)
                With entryWS
                    Set Destination = .Range("J15") 'Define top left cell of our destination
                    Set Destination = Destination.Resize(UBound(CopyRange, 1), UBound(CopyRange, 2)) 'Resize it per the bounds of our array
                    Destination.Value = CopyRange 'write the array to our newly resized destination range
                End With
                Exit For
            Else
                MsgBox "Initials not found on row: " & Cell.Row
            End If
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

### Screenshots

The values in columns C, D and E represent the cell address. 
[image: Screenshot of sample input data]

The output as expected to the resized Destination starting from J15
[image: Output after running the code]

### To delete rows:

Consider this code for just removing the data from the cells...

```
If answer = vbYes Then 
'Delete Cell.Row + the following 9 rows' 

.Range(.Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Column), .Cells(Cell.Offset(9, 0).Row, Cell.Column)).ClearContents 
Exit For
```

Note this is not tested but is the right syntax. This statement would only clear the column the referenced `Cell` relates to, but the range  starts from the cell and extends +9 rows.

*You could then loop through your sheet and delete rows based on blank cells. This is a fairly slow way to do it but useful if you have inconsistent gaps.*

**Note:** `ClearContents will remove values *and* formulas from the range.

---

If you want to delete the rows also to avoid gaps in your data you can define your range and use the `EntireRow.Delete` method...

```
If answer = vbYes Then 
'Delete Cell.Row + the following 9 rows' 

.Range(.Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Column), .Cells(Cell.Offset(9, 0).Row, Cell.Column)).EntireRow.ClearContents 
Exit For
```

If you have having problems with this method, consider adding a break point at that line (<kbd>F9</kbd>) and then run your code. When it breaks at that line, check the range is correct (type `?.Range(.Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Column), .Cells(Cell.Offset(9, 0).Row, Cell.Column)).Address` into the immediate window and hit enter).

Comment: @ChristianAdrianJensen I realised a mistake after the fact (got the resize the wrong way around) - edited and fixed now.

Comment: Thank you! It's almost there, the only thing is that it's nothing pasting the values into the designated range correctly - I've attached an additional picture for visuals of how it should look.

Comment: @ChristianAdrianJensen I've updated my answer with a bit more info of what/how I've done it and added some screenshots of my testing - I found another small error which was causing the data to be written the wrong way around - I removed `Application.Transpose` so now the line is `Destination.Value = CopyRange`

Comment: You're phenomenal Mr! All I needed to add was a "Exit For"!

I don't know how else I am supposed to show appreciation here on the forum, but I would like to give you a BIG thank you for taking out so much of your time - I've learned so much from you in getting this function to work and you've made my first experience here on Stack Overflow absolutely wonderful! :)

Comment: If there is any other form - besides upvoting and marking as solution - of improving your credibility here on the forum please tell so I can get right on it! ;-)

Comment: Best thing to do is mark the answer as accepted if it was the solution to your issue (I'll add the `Exit For` into the loop to reflect your comment), that way others looking to the same (or similar) problems can see it resolved your problem quickly. Good luck with your coding!

Comment: Should I perhaps change topic description to something more relevant? How do you think?

Comment: Its OK how it is. If you do change it make sure its clearer and adds more value otherwise leave it. Others can always suggest edits too anyway.

Comment: I stumbled upon a little problem; a function which deletes it instead. See edit. If you have the time, I'd greatly appreciate it! :)

Comment: @ChristianAdrianJensen Try using the [Range.ClearContents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clearcontents) method. E.g `Range("A1:D10").ClearContents`. If you need anything further you are best to create a new question rather than add on to this one.

Comment: @ChristianAdrianJensen I've updated the answer to address your edit.

Comment: Thanks - ClearContents works, but over time there will be a lot of gaps between the data. I've sat and tried for hours on end to make the function register the rows containing the initials and month but to no success. Since you suggested ClearContents I wonder if it because it becomes tedious to do it with '.Rows' method?

Comment: I've edited my second 'edit'? agian. Notice the *** THIS DOESNT WORK ***

Comment: @ChristianAdrianJensen another edit to the answer has been made to address your edit. Again, you should be asking this in another question next time as it's an entirely new question not *actually* related to the topic of your original.

Comment: That works smoothly now! I kept trying to put the copy(delete)Range into the parenthesis and then use method .Rows(deleteRange).EntireRow.Delete - not realizing that I should just instantiate it exactly where its needed! Thanks agian Samuel, my task is finished! As you maybe have noticed I now have a perfect application which I can hand to the employees to register their tasks and workload for coming months! :D